# Как открыть ссылку на youtube из своего приложения

Tags: android, видео, youtube

Нужно разместить в приложении видео с youtube. Но при клике по нему пользователь должен переходить в официальное приложение youtube(ну или чтобы появлялся выбор чем открыть). Т.е. чтоб не воспроизводился в самом приложении, а перекидывало в браузер или в приложение Youtube. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция открывает видео по заданному id в youtube приложении, если приложение не найдено, то в браузере.

```
public void watchYoutubeVideo(String id){
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
    try {
        startActivity(appIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)